# cakephp view printing out the same values from database

Tags: cakephp

created a view function and any time i click the link to view a `template`, the url at the top of the page is correct but it spits out the same list of `fields` in the database.

the fields are

```
accounts - id, company name, abn
template - id, name, description, account_id
field - id, name, field type, template_id

function view(){

    $accounts=$this->User->AccountsUser->find('list',
    array('fields'=>array('id', 'account_id'),
    'conditions' =>array('user_id' => 
    $this->Auth->user('id'))));

    $templates=$this->Template->find('first', 
    array('conditions' => array(
    'Template.account_id' => $accounts)));

    $fields=$this->Field->find('all', 
    array('conditions' => array(
    'Field.template_id' => Set::extract('/Template/id', $templates))));


    $this->set('template', $templates);
    $this->set('account', $accounts);
    $this->set('field', $fields);


}
```

here is the view

```
    <div class = "conlinks">
    </br></br></br></br></br><h2>Here is your template fields</h2></br>
                    <?php foreach($field as $fields): ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td align='center'><?php echo $fields['Field']['name']; ?>
                    </tr></br>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

so the problem is its grabbing the exact same list of fields, not the correct `template_id` when it prints out the fields

Comment: foreach($field as $fields)     :)

Comment: ? i am unsure in what i need to change?

Comment: @als: the think is that this is actually correct in this case (doesnt make any sense semantically, though) because he passes down $field containing the fields..^^ @ user14... you should really work on your $variable labeling. its one huge mess. look at your templates. it should be singular since you do find(first) etc. no-one including yourself can understand this without making errors. and changing them all the time doesnt help either. same with account. last but not least you should not use previous search results without checking on empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was I wasn't getting the parameters when click the link

```
function view($name){

$fields = $this->Template->Field->find('list',array( 
          'fields'=> array('name'),
          'conditions' => array(
          'template_id'=> $name)));
$this->set('field', $fields);


}
```

and the view

```
<div class = "conlinks">
        </br><h2>Here is your template fields</h2>

                        <?php foreach($field as $name): ?>
                        <tr>
                        <td align='center'>
                        <?php echo $name; ?>
                        </tr></br>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </br>

<?php
echo $this->Html->link('Back', '/templates/view', array('class' => 'button'));?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to debug this for yourself. Just narrow the bug down step by step.

For starters, in your view function, do a print_r on the following variables, and make sure each one contains a logical result:

- $accounts
- $templates
- $fields

If you find unexpected results there, I'd be looking at the parameters you pass into each of your finds, and making sure they're OK. You're passing in $accounts as an array to your find condition - make sure it matches the format that cake expects. Do the same for Set::extract('/Template/id', $templates).

Also look at the SQL that Cake is producing.

If you're not already using it, I'd highly recommend installing Cake's Debug Kit Toolbar - https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/ because it makes debugging variables and SQL much easier.

If you do the above steps and can't solve your problem, you should at least be able to narrow it down to a line or two of code. Update your answer to show what line or two is causing the problem, and include print_r's of some of the variables you're working with. That should help others on StackOverflow to give you a specific answer.

Hope that helps!